# Javascript stop submission of submit button even if someone selects browser "prevent this page from creating additional dialogs”

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, firefox

I have this code I use to validate something:

```
    if (document.getElementById('ANYNUMBER').innerHTML > 5){
        alert("You are doing something wrong.");
return false;
    }
```

If you keep submitting in a form, on the second or third time, depending on the browser software, it gives you the option to select "prevent this page from creating additional dialogs” which in Chrome it still does not submit the form but in other programs such as Firefox, it stops the alert() dialog but also allows it to submit causing problems.

How can I prevent the form from submitting if this alert() is still being activated but not showing up due to the disabling of the dialog?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add e.preventDefault() to your form submission function. It will prevent the default submission, allowing you only to submit if the form is valid.

Comment: P.S. You should use `parseInt` or something, because `innerHTML` is a string. (Just for clarity)

Comment: Just use something other than alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've run into a potential bug in Firefox:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=633154

The problem is that once the alert is disabled by the user, trying to call `alert()` will throw an exception in Firefox, whereas in Chrome it will just ignore it.

One way to get around this is to use a `try/catch` block (though it does feel a bit hacky):

```
if (document.getElementById('ANYNUMBER').innerHTML > 5){
  try {
    alert( "You are doing something wrong." );
  }
  catch(e) {
  }

  return false;
}
```

Also, you are probably going to run into a usability issue if users disable the alert and then won't know whats wrong and why their form isn't submitting. Probably best to show the message somewhere on the page itself. Just my two cents though.

Comment: Thank you @go-oleg. Can you suggest how the error, or any error for validation of a form, can be brought up in a DIV instead using either PHP or Javascript the same way as in the question instead, so without alert()? I would appreciate if you could explain and it would be a good example for others looking of what to do better. Thanks.

Comment: I know you can hide the DIV with display:none; and then use javascript to activate the corresponding DIVs. How would that be done again?